# eOS 5.1 on Dell Inspiron 5301

Tags: dell

Anyone tried installing 5.1.Hera on Dell Inspiron 5301
Installation works ok.

However from the Grub menu, when eOS is selected, it goes to a blank screen with a blinking cursor. It seem to never recover from there.

Ubuntu 20.10 works fine on the same setup though.

Answer (score 0):

In the Grub menu, select Advanced options for elementary, and try booting into recovery mode (if there are multiple choices with different kernel versions then keep trying until hopefully one of them boots). If that works and you get to a command line then look at the log files for anything suspicious that might tell you why the OS is not starting properly.